# Check if an array of files exist in a directory and check for a pattern in the name of the files in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I have 4 files in a particuar Directory, say

```
GateTime_20190702.csv

RemoteTime_20190702.csv

Employee_20190702.csv

Random_20190702.csv.
```

I want to check if all the files exist in that particular folder.
If all of them exist, I need to check if the file names start with the String before '_'. and also the date for which the files have been generated like
'20190702'.

I have tried the code, but can't seem to figure out how to check for all files in a loop, plus even check for the pattern in the file name.

`if [[ -f GateTime_20190702.csv && -f RemoteTime_20190702.csv ]];` then

I want to check if all 4 files are present in the directory or not, and if yes, then the pattern should match the desired pattern.

Comment: Are the 4 prefixes always the same?  Do you know the date on the end in advance?  What are the inputs to your script? What should be the output?

Comment: Yes, the prefixes will be the same... the date is also known.

Comment: With bash: `ls {GateTime,RemoteTime,Employee,Random}_20190702.csv >/dev/null || echo "Error"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bash:

```
postfix="20190702"
prefixes="GateTime RemoteTime Employee Random"

for prefix in $prefixes; do
  name="${prefix}_${postfix}.csv"

  # Check if the file does not exist
  if [[ ! -e "$name" ]]; then
    echo "Error"
    break
  fi
done
```

This will output nothing if all four files with the correct name exist in the current directory and will output `Error` if at least one file does not exist with the correct name.